# Can we deploy two struts2 applications in same app server?

Tags: java, deployment, struts2, application-server

I have an application in Struts2 that is configured in Eclipse and it is running fine.

Now I want to deploy that application with different name, So I have created new web application and deployed to server.

Now I see that exception on eclipse console..

> SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts
>   Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]  at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:449)

Is there any bug in Struts2, which does not allow you to deploy two Struts2 applications in same app server?

Comment: please add your configuration

Comment: Normally you'd try to provide the complete stack trace that would indicate *why* the filter failed startup. There are any number of things that could be going wrong, including Eclipse-specific deployment issues.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to deploy any number of instances of the same application on the same server by giving different names to the `<context-root>` tag in your `web.xml`